# culprit vs. perpetrator

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Are there any differences between a *culprit* and a *perpetrator*?

In what cases would *perpetrator* be preferred to *culprit*?

The only difference I can think of is that *culprit* is a broader term and can refer to **something** as well as **someone**. As seen in the following example, the *culprit* is the H3H2.

> The main culprit for this harsh flu season is the predominant strain, H3N2.

And *perpetrator* is always referring to a **someone** who has committed a wrongdoing.

Comment: Your example sentence indicates the difference. The culprit, the particular flu strain, has actually done nothing apart from exist. But it is still culpable. To be a _perpetrator_ would require some significant, cogent activity, I would say. A stone could be the 'culprit' in a situation where someone broke their foot. But it would not be called a 'perpetrator' as the thing was just sitting there when someone tripped over it.

Comment: Please show us your research findings.

Comment: research:  'The main culprit for this harsh flu season is the predominant strain, H3N2'  Sparse ... but at least some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*perpetrator*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/perpetrator) is someone who commits a crime (or other illegal activity). [From Latin *perpetrare*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/perpetrator), "to perform, accomplish"

A [*culprit*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/culprit) is someone who is guilty of a crime (or charged with one). The first part is the same as in *culpable*, from the [Latin for *guilt*](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/culpa) (*culpa*)

You can be guilty of a crime without actually doing anything, such as standing by and not helping someone in distress. Negligence is something which would be a non-activity which would have a culprit, but not a perpetrator.

In your example, the virus is a culprit, but lacking intention/agency cannot be called a perpetrator. Your observation about 'someone/something' reflects this, in that inanimate things cannot be perpetrators, only culprits.

Answer (score 1):

**Perpetrator versus culprit**   [wikidifference](https://wikidiff.com/perpetrator/culprit)

> **Perpetrator** is one who perpetrates [**doing** the crime]; especially, one who commits an
>   offense or crime. **Culprit** is the person or thing **at fault** for a
>   problem or crime.

Answer (score 1):

- A perpetrator is only a person who commits a crime or criminal act.
- A culprit is a person or thing you can blame for something.

In lay terms, a virus or germ can be a culprit but not a perpetrator.

> More Diseases Pinned on Old culprit: Germs

culprit, is of course, used in other contexts that are not to do with diseases..

For example:

> [Political ideology](https://bigthink.com/aeon-ideas/what-makes-people-distrust-science-surprisingly-not-politics) is seen by many researchers as the main culprit of
>   science skepticism.

[Use of culprit re germs in the press](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/05/17/health/more-diseases-pinned-on-old-culprit-germs.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think 'perpetrator' refers to someone committing a crime towards another Person. 
were culprit can refer to anything